# Young, independent Markov, looking for a chain.

Tags: markov-chains, independence

I'm having trouble doing the "$\Longrightarrow$" part of the first proof, which is Lemma 1 from page 6, from [these](http://www2.math.uu.se/~takis/L/McRw/mcrw.pdf) lecture notes. In the lecture notes the proof is a one-liner, from which I can't infer, how an explicit proof goes.

What is to be shown is that if $(X_m)_{m\geq 0}$ is a Markov process ***[*** which is defined as meaning 
$$ (X_m)_{m>n} | X_n = i_n$$(which is a conditional random variable, taking values in $S\times S \times \cdots $, the set of infinitely long tuples from $S$, where $S$ denotes the state space) is independent of $$ (X_m)_{m<n} | X_n = i_n,$$(which similarly is  a conditional random variable, taking values in $S^n$) for any $n$ and $i_0,\ldots ,i_{n+1} \in S$**]**, then $$P(X_{n+1}=i_{n+1} \mid X_n=i_n,\ldots, X_0=i_0)=P(X_{n+1}=i_{n+1} \mid X_n=i_n).$$

How can I do this ?

Comment: The equation $$P[X_{n+1} = i_{n+1} \mid X_n = i_n, \ldots , X_0=i_0] = P[X_{n+1} = i_{n+1} |X_n=i_n]  \quad \forall n \in \{0, 1, 2, \ldots\} $$ and for all $\{i_k\}$ taking values in the state space, is usually considered as the _definition_ of a discrete time Markov chain (and seems simpler than the definition you give).  Once you define it like this, you can _prove_ that future values are conditionally independent of the past, given the current state, for example $$ P[X_{n+2} = i_{n+2} \mid X_n=i_n, \ldots, X_0=i_0] = P[X_{n+2}=i_{n+2}|X_n=i_n] $$ This seems more direct and intuitive.

Comment: @Michael That is true. But actually, on the lecture notes that I linked to, it is shown that my definition is equivalent to your - and my question is actually about a part from the proof of that equivalence.

Comment: For your information, the object $$(X_m)_{m>n} \mid X_n = i_n$$ is not a random variable (actually this object does not exist at all). (Unrelated: I cannot understand your title, what do you mean by it?)

Comment: I like the witty title.  I would not define a Markov chain in the way of your notes, though.

Comment: @Did I wanted to express (if that makes sense) $(X_m)_{m>n}$ restricted to $X_n=i_n$. That makes sense, right? Would $(X_m)_{m>n}\Big| _{\{ X_n=i_n\}}  $ have been a better notation?

Comment: "That makes sense, right? " No. Sorry.

Comment: @Did Is there any other way I could define the conditional (in $X_n = i_N$) future (resp. past) process as stand-alone processes, in order to talk about them being independent and not conditionally independent? The idea is to move the conditional from the "independent" to the definition of the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $i_n$ and define $P^{i_n}(B):=P(B|X_n=i_n)$ for any event $B$. Let $A$ be the event $\{X_{n-1}=i_{n-1},\ldots,X_0=i_0\}$. Then conditional independence implies
$$P^{i_n}(\{X_{n+1}=i_{n+1}\}\cap A)=P^{i_n}(X_{n+1}=i_{n+1})P^{i_n}(A).$$
Using the definition of conditional probability, we have
$$P(X_{n+1}=i_{n+1}\,|\,X_n=i_n,\ldots,X_0=i_0)=P^{i_n}(X_{n+1}=i_{n+1}\,|\,A)=\frac{P^{i_n}(\{X_{n+1}=i_{n+1}\}\cap A)}{P^{i_n}(A)}\\=\frac{P^{i_n}(X_{n+1}=i_{n+1})P^{i_n}(A)}{P^{i_n}(A)}=P(X_{n+1}=i_{n+1}\,|\,X_n=i_n).$$

EDIT: It seems like your main concern is notational, so I'll give some more details. If $B$ is some event, we might write $P^B(C):=P(C|B)$. The reason for this is that $P^B$ is just another probability measure (i.e. $P^B(\emptyset)=0$ and $P^B$ is countably additive), so we can do everything with $P^B$ that we can with $P$. Your main confusion seems to be how to make sense of $P^B(A|C)$, so let's unpack it using the definitions:
$$P^B(C|A):=\frac{P^B(C\cap A)}{P^B(A)}=\frac{P(C\cap A|B)}{P(A|B)}=\frac{\frac{P(C\cap A\cap B)}{P(B)}}{\frac{P(A\cap B}{P(B)}}=\frac{P(C\cap A\cap B)}{P(A\cap B)}=P(C|A\cap B).$$
This agrees with intuition: the conditional probability given $B$, of $C$, given $A$, is the same as the probability of $C$ given both $A$ and $B$. I did not explain that to you, so I apologize for that.

With that in mind, hopefully what you referred to as "the third line from the bottom" is now clear: in our case, $B$ is the event $\{X_n=i_n\}$, $C$ is the event $\{X_{n+1}=i_{n+1}\}$, and $A$ is as defined up top. Then what I have written is *precisely* $P(C|B\cap A)=P^B(C|A)$. The next equality is just definition of conditional probability: $P^B(C|A)=\frac{P^B(C\cap A)}{P^B(A)}$. And the next line is what uses our assumption of conditional independence: $C$ ("the future") and $A$ ("the past") are independent conditioned on $B$ ("the present"), which precisely means that $P^B(C\cap A)=P^B(C)P^B(A)$.

Perhaps there is also confusion where I write $\{X_n=i_n,X_{n-1}=i_{n-1}\}$ instead of $\{X_n=i_n\}\cap\{X_{n-1}=i_{n-1}\}$, but I would encourage you to get used to such abbreviations as they are abundant in probability theory. Likewise, the use of $P^{i_n}$ is particularly common in Markov chain analysis. For homogeneous Markov chains in particular, the initial distribution (that is, the distribution of $X_0$) is largely irrelevant and it is both easier and more useful to consider probabilities of the form $P^x:=P(\cdot|X_0=x)$ for each $x\in S$.

As a final note, I will ask you to please watch your tone in comments. This probably wasn't intentional, but you came across quite hostile at times when I was only trying to help.

Comment: Could you edit your answer slighty? It'S quite hard to read the way it is because there are a number of typos in it, for example $B$ doesn't appear in the definintion (I guess you meant $A$) and are you sure you mean $P^{i_n}$ on the RHS on the third row from the bottom and not just $P$ ?

Comment: And also, where comes conditional expectation into play?

Comment: I've edited the typo in the definition of $P^{i_n}$, but everything else is correct. Why do you think we need conditional expectation?

Comment: I'm not sure, but in your third line form the top it says "conditional expectation"

Comment: Ah apologies, I meant independence! How does it look now?

Comment: Could you elaborate why the equation from the third row from the bottom holds, i.e. prove it more explciitly? (Among other things, I'm still confused why $P^{i_n}$ should be there, since  $$P^{i_n}(X_{n+1}=i_{n+1}|A)=  P((X_{n+1}=i_{n+1}|A)|A)=  P(X_{n+1}=i_{n+1}|A),$$so why write $P^{i_n}$ instead of $P$ in the irst place? This then has a bearing on the next lines...)

Comment: I don't know which equality you mean by "third row from the bottom", but you seem to have a misunderstanding how conditioning works. Writing $P((X_{n+1}=i_{n+1}|A)|A)$ doesn't make sense - what is $X_{n+1}=i_{n+1}|A$ as an event? Your conclusion is not correct - it is essential that you retain the $P^{i_n}$ (otherwise we end up with $P(X_{n+1}=i_{n+1})$. All I have used is the definition of conditional probability ($P(A|B):=P(A\cap B)/P(B)$) and conditional independence ($P(A\cap B|C)=P(A|C)P(B|C)$).

Comment: If it helps, you can think of $P^{i_n}$ as just another probability measure. All the classical results hold with $P$ replaced by $P^{i_n}$. In this context, if $S$ is countable (as is the case being considered for your lemma), then $\{X_m,m>n\}$ being independent of $\{X_k,k<n\}$ conditionally on $X_n$ *by definition* means that
$$P^x(X_{n+1}\in A_1,\ldots,X_{n+j}\in A_j,X_{n-1}\in B_{n-1},\ldots,X_0\in B_0)=P^x(X_{n+1}\in A_1,\ldots,X_{n+j}\in A_j)P^x(B_{n-1},\ldots,X_0\in B_0)$$
for every $x\in S$ and $j>0$, where as before $P^x:=P(\,\cdot\,|X_n=x)$.

Comment: The third line is this one: $$P(X_{n+1}=i_{n+1}\,|\,X_n=i_n,\ldots,X_0=i_0)=P^{i_n}(X_{n+1}=i_{n+1}\,|\,A)$$ I can't understand how you could *not* get what I meant by the third row. I'm still convinced that your proof is incomplete!  My impression is that while I assume you have the right proof idea, you didn't  really actually check your proof. The fact that you  you had previously typos -twice in a row! and it took me to times regarding the "conditional expectation" to make you realize that- seems to support my hunch. [...]

Comment: [...] For a bounty and probably a simple question -that is still unclear to me though, see below- I really would have expected an answer that gets it right at least the second time, because the time I spend writing all these comments is already considerable!  Also the upvote ratio between my question and you answer is not looking good for the answer seems to indicate that the answer is unclear as it stands to other people as well. Now, after these criticism which I'm afraid had to be mentioned: Yes, $P((X_{n+1}=i_{n+1}|A)|A)$ doesn't make sense. [...]

Comment: [...] Yet this is basically what you wrote, if you unpack the right-hand side of the displayed equation above in my first comment today, which is still unclear to me. A small typo on my side was that the right-hand side actually reads $P((X_{n+1}=i_{n+1}|A)|\{X_n = i_n\})$, if you unpack the definition of $P^{i_n}$, instead of $P((X_{n+1}=i_{n+1}|A)|A)$. So somethin is still problematic here. I think the $P^{i_n}$ did more harm than good in this case. Can you please, finally, clarify this?

Comment: Reading through the comments, I also can't see why this proof should be correct. Incredible that it got the bounty...

Comment: @Jason P.S. Sorry about the "third row from the bottom". I viewed the question on a different display and found that there are just two rows, not three. But my comment above should clarify anyway what I mean. I still hope that you can clarify your answer.

Comment: @elle I've added some more details, hopefully you understand what I'm talking about now.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications, unpacking the notation (the iterated conditioning) really clarified it for me. I apologize for the partly hostile tone - but I hope you can see from my perspective how frustrating it was, when I spent days after the answer  still not understanding it. But now thankfully everything is clear and I accepted it.